# How to get access to system folders when enumerating directories?

Tags: c#, .net, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I am using this code:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\");
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    MessageBox.Show(file.FullName);
}
```

I get this error:

> **UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled**
>
> Access to the path 'D:\System Volume Information\' is denied.

How might I solve this?

Comment: Run program with an account that has permissions?

Comment: i actually want to fix this...

Comment: what should i add to my code so that program can ignore **System folders Windows?** for search

Comment: That's not what you asked, Haji.

Comment: yes... but
fix means that
i want to search between by Accessed Folders...
how would i do that?

Comment: System Volume Information stores restore point data.  It is not accessible even with an admin account.  You need to use GetDirectories() and skip directories you cannot access.  Avoid directories that have FileAttributes.System and Hidden set.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in .NET to override privileges of the user you are running this code as.

There's only 1 option really. Make sure only admin runs this code or you run it under admin account.
It is advisable that you either put "try catch" block and handle this exception or
before you run the code you check that the user is an administrator:

```
WindowsIdentity currentIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal currentPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(currentIdentity);
if (currentPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator))
{
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\");
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
MessageBox.Show(file.FullName);
}
}
```

Comment: Additionally, you can *require* that the application be run as administrator in the manifest. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276674/how-to-force-a-wpf-application-to-run-in-administrator-mode/5276770#5276770

Comment: where to put **try-catch statement.**
try catch statement should not break my loop

Answer (score 1):

try calling this method putting one more try catch block before calling - this will mean top folder lacks required authorisation:

```
     static void RecursiveGetFiles(string path)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        try
        {

            foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(file.FullName);
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Access denied to folder: " + path);
        }

        foreach (DirectoryInfo lowerDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            try
            {
                RecursiveGetFiles(lowerDir.FullName);

            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Access denied to folder: " + path);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Problem is here in
`FileInfo[] files =   dir.GetFiles("*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);`

Comment: when we call `dir.GetFiles("*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);`
program starts file search including "System Volume Information" folder
that generates exception

Comment: can you try above... This doesn't search in a directory unless user has required privileges. I've run it against my C drive and it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot...
that was my requiremet :-)

Comment: if this has worked for you please mark my answer as correct, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can manually search the file tree ignoring system directories.

```
// Create a stack of the directories to be processed.
Stack<DirectoryInfo> dirstack = new Stack<DirectoryInfo>();
// Add your initial directory to the stack.
dirstack.Push(new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\");

// While there are directories on the stack to be processed...
while (dirstack.Count > 0)
{
    // Set the current directory and remove it from the stack.
    DirectoryInfo current = dirstack.Pop();

    // Get all the directories in the current directory.
    foreach (DirectoryInfo d in current.GetDirectories())
    {
        // Only add a directory to the stack if it is not a system directory.
        if ((d.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) != FileAttributes.System)
        {
            dirstack.Push(d);
        }
    }

    // Get all the files in the current directory.
    foreach (FileInfo f in current.GetFiles())
    {
        // Do whatever you want with the files here.
    }
}
```